# Pass parameters to ConTeXt \component, \product, etc

Tags: context, context-mkiv, parameters

I would like to use, and it appears suited, the `\component` and related commands in ConTeXt. However, I would like to have multiple parameters to a given component e.g.

```
\startcomponent X
  \sometexcommand{name} % where name is a parameter that varies the component
\stopcomponent
```

One way to accomplish this might be to set Lua variables as side-effects, but I was wondering if there was a way to directly pass arguments to components e.g.

```
\component[X][name=123]
```

Then use something like `\structureuservariable{name}`

If a component is not suited for this, is there a sensible alternative one might suggest?

Comment: Why not use a `module` instead of a `component`. You can pass parameters to modules.

Answer (score 3):

Components do not take parameters but [modules](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules) do.

Save this as `t-X.tex` (`t-` stands for third-party)

```
\startmodule X

\sometexcommand{\currentmoduleparameter{name}} % where name is a parameter that varies the component

\stopmodule
```

And use the module in your main document.

```
\starttext

\usemodule[X][name=123]

\stoptext
```

This will of course not compile because `\sometexcommand` is undefined.